# Check function params (or object without create variable) in typescript

Tags: typescript

I want check params of ajax req and res
I have some ajax Interface

```
export interface AjaxLibraryCreateDirectoryReq {
  attributes: {
    name: string
  }
  source: string
}
```

When i make ajax i try check type:

```
axios.post('ajax/library/directories', {
        attributes: {
          name: name
        },
        source: this.props.location.query.id
      }: AjaxLibraryCreateDirectoryReq ).then(...
```

but it does not work, how i can do it?

Comment: doesn't work means? - what errors do you get?

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because typescript compiles to JS and it is that compiled JS that runs. There is no type information associated with it during run time.

You can try [io-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts) but it has its own unique way of providing validation.